# Querying by a pod field

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

I have a custom pod, `product_type`, in that pod I have a custom field named `label`. I want to find all the pods where the `label` matches a certain strings.

Iv been trying this (and some other variations):

```
$mypod = pods('product_type', array(
    'where'   => 'product_type.label LIKE "%'.$someLabelString.'%"',
    'limit'=>-1
));
```

I've also tried changing the `product_type.label` part of the query to `t.label`, but to no avail. I get this error:

```
Database Error; SQL: SELECT DISTINCT `t`.* FROM `wp_posts` AS `t` WHERE ( ( `product_type`.`label` LIKE "%hello%" ) AND ( `t`.`post_type` = "product_type" ) AND ( `t`.`post_status` IN ( "publish" ) ) ) ORDER BY `t`.`menu_order`, `t`.`post_title`, `t`.`post_date`; Response: Unknown column 'product_type.label' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a super handy break down of what field syntax to use for each pod type:

http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/find/#additional-information

Custom simple lists consist of a label (for display) and a value (the underlying “raw” value). For the ‘where’ parameter, you probably need to check against whatever you set as the ‘value’.

When you create a simple custom defined list, a box becomes available for “Custom Defined Options”. As the help pop-up says: “One option per line, use value|Label for separate values and labels”

If you added the label field to your pod, you would just use product_type.label if your pod is table-based for storage, otherwise if it’s meta-based you would use label.meta_value

Comment: `t.label` if your pod is an ACT, `label.meta_value` if your pod is a meta-based Pod, `related_field.label` if you are accessing your field through a relationship to another Pod, `d.label` if you are using a CPT / User pod but using the Table storage type.